# Encode enum.Enum type with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I’m trying to serialize and deserialize a dataclass that has a enum member using `ruamel.yaml`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object
import enum

yaml = YAML()

write_file = "out.yaml"

@enum.unique
@yaml_object(yaml)
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    ZERO = 0
    ONE = 1

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(f'!{cls.__name__}:',
                                            u'{.name}'.format(node))

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        breakpoint() # never hits this
        return cls[node.value]


@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    foo: str
    bar: MyEnum

myobj = MyClass("hello", MyEnum.ZERO)

with open(write_file, "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(myobj, f)

with open(write_file, "r") as f:
    print(yaml.load(f))
```

Serialized `out.yaml`:

```
!MyClass
foo: hello
bar: !MyEnum: ZERO
```

My code serializes and deserializes, but it doesn’t properly reconstruct the enum field. It never even calls `from_yaml()`.

Current output:

```
MyClass(foo='hello', bar=<ruamel.yaml.comments.TaggedScalar object at 0x7f37221c5a90>)
```

Expected output:

```
MyClass(foo='hello', bar=MyEnum.ZERO)
```

I’ve searched through the docs, source, and scoured the internet for examples, can’t quite figure this one out.

Open to using other Yaml serializers/deserializers if they would work better in this case, but it *feels* like this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You represent instances of your class `MyEnum` with the tag `MyEnum:` (including trailing colon),
but you never specify how to load that tag. `yaml_object` takes the class name itself as tag (without colon).

If you leave out the colon from the first argument to `represent_scalar` the breakpoint is hit without problem.

You might want to make add a `__repr__` method to `MyEnum` to get the output you want:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object
import enum

yaml = YAML()

write_file = "out.yaml"

@enum.unique
@yaml_object(yaml)
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    ZERO = 0
    ONE = 1

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(f'!{cls.__name__}',
                                            u'{.name}'.format(node))

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        print('breakpoint hit')
        return cls[node.value]


@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    foo: str
    bar: MyEnum

myobj = MyClass("hello", MyEnum.ZERO)

with open(write_file, "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(myobj, f)

with open(write_file, "r") as f:
    print(yaml.load(f))
```

which gives:

```
breakpoint hit
MyClass(foo='hello', bar=<MyEnum.ZERO: 0>)
```